# Tic-Tac-Toe code refactor and win logic C++

Tags: c++, refactoring, tic-tac-toe

I've been trying to get back to Programming and starting with good ol' c++. It's been 10 years since I've tried to write anything of value in c++ when I was 12 years old. I have been away from programming altogether and tried to build a tic-tac-toe from scratch without any outside help. I gave up in the win logic because I tried so hard and couldn't make it work. If you guys could help out a bit, I'd appreciate it a lot.
**PS. I'm gonna post the entire code and if you guys think there's some refactoring I could do, I'd really really appreciate it.**

I only tried to check wins in a 'row' but couldn't get it.

Here's the mess (lol):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void drawBoard(char board[3][3]);
bool searchBoard(char x, char board[3][3], char p);
void play(int player, char board[3][3]);
int checkWin(char board[3][3]);
int main() {
   char board[3][3] = {
       {'1', '2', '3'}, 
       {'4', '5', '6'}, 
       {'7', '8', '9'}
       };
   char p1, p2;
   cout<<endl<<endl<<"*******WELCOME TO TIC-TAC-TOE*******"<<endl<<endl<<endl;
   drawBoard(board);
   play(1, board);
   play(2, board);
   play(1, board);
   play(2, board);
   play(1, board);
   int d = checkWin(board);
   if(d == 1) {
       cout<<"WIN!";
   }
   play(2, board);
   play(1, board);
   play(2, board);
   play(1, board);
   getchar();
}
void drawBoard(char board[3][3]) {
   cout<<"\t||\t||\t"<<endl;
   cout<<"   "<<board[0][0]<<"    ||   "<<board[0][1]<<"  ||   "<<board[0][2]<<endl;
   cout<<"\t||\t||\t"<<endl;
   cout<<"=========================="<<endl;
   cout<<"\t||\t||\t"<<endl;
   cout<<"   "<<board[1][0]<<"    ||   "<<board[1][1]<<"  ||   "<<board[1][2]<<endl;
   cout<<"\t||\t||\t"<<endl;
   cout<<"=========================="<<endl;
   cout<<"\t||\t||\t"<<endl;
   cout<<"   "<<board[2][0]<<"    ||   "<<board[2][1]<<"  ||   "<<board[2][2]<<endl;
   cout<<"\t||\t||\t"<<endl;
}
bool searchBoard(char x, char board[3][3], char p) {
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
           if(board[i][j] == x) {
               board[i][j] = p;
               return 1;
           }
       }
   }
   return 2;
}
void play(int player, char board[3][3]) {
   char p, mark;
   if(player == 1) {
       cout<<"Player 1"<<endl;
       mark = 'X';
   } else {
       cout<<"Player 2"<<endl;
       mark = 'O';
   }
   A:
   cin>>p;
   int x = searchBoard(p, board, mark);
   if (x == 2) {
       cout<<endl<<"Not Found"<<endl<<"Try again!"<<endl;
       drawBoard(board);
       goto A;
   } if (x == 0) {
       cout<<endl<<"Taken!"<<endl<<"Try again!"<<endl;
       drawBoard(board);
       goto A;
   }
   if (x == 1) {
       true;
   }
   drawBoard(board);
}
int checkWin(char board[3][3]) {
   int counter;
   for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
       if(board[0][i] == 'X') {
           counter++;
       }
       if(counter == 3) {
           return 1;
       }
   }
   for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
       if(board[1][i] == 'X') {
           counter++;
       }
       if(counter == 3) {
           return 1;
       }
   }
   for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
       if(board[2][i] == 'X') {
           counter++;
       }
       if(counter == 3) {
           return 1;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Albeit a little messy, you could get rid of the for loops and just have a series of if statements checking each row, column, and diagonal. i.e. for row 1: `if (board[0][0] == 'X' && board[0][1] == 'X' && board[0][2] == 'X') return 1;`.  For a diagonal: `if (board[0][0] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X') return 1;`.

Comment: @mlb6300 That seems a better approach. Thank you! I'll try that <3